# Grails functional-test plugin, set the body in the Post

Tags: grails, post, functional-testing

I am using functional-test plugin to test my REST web services. I cannot set the content of body in a correct way. This is my code:

```
class HelloWorldFunctionalTests extends APITestCase {

    String postJson = "{\"name\":\"test name\"}"

    void testPost() {
        post('/mycontroller') {
            headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'

            body {
                """
                    {name:'test name'}
                """
            }

        }

        //assertStatus 200
    }
}
```

At the moment I am getting:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setBody(HTTPBuilder.java:1200)

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Many Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

It had nothing to do with the way the body was set. What I was missing was the content type.

This line of code made it work fine:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```